# How to enable odbc in XAMPP linux

Tags: php, linux, xampp, odbc

I am working on a php application in which for database connection I am using odbc.
The code is working properly in windows but when I tried the same code in Linux I am facing

> Fatal Error Undefined Function odbc_connect()

I think this error occurs because odbc is not enabled on XAMPP.

Please advoice me how to enable odbc in XAMPP under Linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What http server are you using on Linux?