# Ibm streams connection with mysql database

Tags: database, connection, ibm-streams

I'm using ibm streams 4.2 in centos 6 . I'm trying to use the operator odbcappend to insert the tuples from the file source to a table in my sql db. So I'm trying to connect ibm streams to my sql db. However, I'm using xampp php my admin for my sql. I tried so many ways for the connection but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?" What error message are you getting?

Comment: [This table](https://developer.ibm.com/streamsdev/docs/set-considerations-specialized-toolkits/#db) lists the environment variables that you need to set for MySQL.  Did you set them accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little digging and found this post which leads me to believe that xampp does not use one of the tested ODBC drivers for the toolkit:
xampp post:
[How to enable odbc in XAMPP linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034575/how-to-enable-odbc-in-xampp-linux)
Tested ODBC drivers for mysql:

> UnixODBC v2.3.1 or later with MySQL driver OR
>
> MySQL ODBC Connector Driver v5.3.2 or later

If your mySQL distribution uses the MySQL ODBC Connector then use that or you can download UnixODBC to use with the toolkit.

Otherwise you should use  STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC_UNIX_OTHER and setup the other variables to point to the driver that is already installed.  You should be sucessful to the extent that the ODBC implementation matches the syntax of the tested drivers.   From the docs:

> The operators also allow for more databases that support ODBC by using the UnixODBC driver. To use this capability, define the environment variable STREAMS_ADAPTERS_ODBC_UNIX_OTHER.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCRJU_4.2.0/com.ibm.streams.toolkits.doc/spldoc/dita/tk$com.ibm.streams.db/tk$com.ibm.streams.db$1.html